# Ideas on: Realtime Mist Pass via Shading Nodes?

Tags: node-editor, shaders, render-passes, depth-map, toon-shading

Wouldn't it somehow have to be possible to get a **depth gradient** into one's **material nodes**? This way you could have a **realtime mist pass** in the viewport (like in the picture).

I guess one would need the distance between object surface and camera somehow...

Any Ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is this Camera Data node:

[image]

As you can see, you need to map its Z-depth value to a meaningful range to be a visible color.